# Running selenium test multiple times in testng

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have a suite that has a test with multiple classes.  I need to run this suite multiple times (not in parallel).  In other words run the "FirefoxTests" test 300 times, or 1000 time, etc.  I know how to do this using junit, but I don't using testng which my scripts now have been converted to.  Here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="SuiteEndToEnd" parallel="false" verbose="10" thread-count="2">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="com.bpms.tests.MySuiteListener"/>
    </listeners>
  <test name="FirefoxTests">
    <parameter name="browser" value="firefox"/>
    <classes>
      <class name="com.bpms.tests.InitiateBuyPlan"/>
      <class name="com.bpms.tests.AddItemsToBuyPlan"/>
      <class name="com.bpms.tests.ReviewBuyPlan"/>
      <class name="com.bpms.tests.ApproveBuyPlan"/>
      <class name="com.bpms.tests.ManageQuoteSolicitation"/>
      <class name="com.bpms.tests.StartQuote"/>
      <class name="com.bpms.tests.ReviewQuote"/>
      <class name="com.bpms.tests.RecordInterestInQuotes"/>
      <class name="com.bpms.tests.ReviewCountryBuyIn"/>
      <class name="com.bpms.tests.CompleteItemInfo"/>
      <class name="com.bpms.tests.ReviewItemInformation"/>
      <class name="com.bpms.tests.UpdateInterestInQuote"/>
      <class name="com.bpms.tests.PerformLogisticsAnalysis"/>
      <class name="com.bpms.tests.SecondReview"/>
      <class name="com.bpms.tests.ReviewNLCDiagrams"/>
      <class name="com.bpms.tests.ConfirmItemSpecifications"/>
      <class name="com.bpms.tests.ClassifyItem"/>
      <class name="com.bpms.tests.ApproveItem" />
      <class name="com.bpms.tests.ClassifyItem2"/>
      <class name="com.bpms.tests.CompleteItemClassification"/>
      <class name="com.bpms.tests.ApproveItemClassification"/>
      <class name="com.bpms.tests.SubmitLinkToFreightEstimates"/>
      <class name="com.bpms.tests.ReviewFreightWorksheet"/>
      <class name="com.bpms.tests.ReviewItemInfoAndReviseInterest"/>
      <class name="com.bpms.tests.ManageAnalyzedQuotes"/>
      <class name="com.bpms.tests.AuthorizeItemDevelopment"/>
      <class name="com.bpms.tests.ConsolidateCountryAuthorizations"/>
      <class name="com.bpms.tests.FinalizeItemInformationAndGenerateUnsignedItemAgreementPDF"/>
      <class name="com.bpms.tests.VerifyAndUploadItemDocuments"/>
      <class name="com.bpms.tests.AttachDocsForApproval"/>
      <class name="com.bpms.tests.FinalizeItemForApproval"/>
      <class name="com.bpms.tests.ApproveItemGMM"/>
      <class name="com.bpms.tests.ConsolidateInCountryAGMM_GMMResponses"/>
      <class name="com.bpms.tests.InitiateCodeOfConductForFactory"/>
      <class name="com.bpms.tests.SubmitAuditResultsForFactory"/>
      <class name="com.bpms.tests.ConfirmItemSetupAndPOsIssued"/>
      <class name="com.bpms.tests.VerifyReceiptsOfPOs"/>
      <class name="com.bpms.tests.ConfirmReceiptOfPOs"/>
      <class name="com.bpms.tests.ReviewQAProductionTestResults"/>
      <class name="com.bpms.tests.CompleteProjectChecklist"/>
      <class name="com.bpms.tests.VerifySupplierCodeOfConductForFactory"/>
      <class name="com.bpms.tests.VerifyChainSecurityForFactory"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- FirefoxTests -->
</suite> <!-- SuiteEndToEnd -->
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way from the xml but one way that this can be done simply without really adding too much effort is to write up an implementation for ITestListener

In the onStart method you can set the invocation count for all the methods in the test.
for eg.

```
public void onStart(ITestContext context) {

     if(context.getName().equals("FFTests")) {
        for(ITestNGMethod met : context.getAllTestMethods()){
            met.setInvocationCount(200);
        }
    }

}
```

If the same needs to be done at the suite level then implement the IsuiteListener onStart method similarly.